# relation between $\zeta(2)$ and the fourier transform of $x^2$

Tags: fourier-series

I have problem with see the relation between the transform of $x^2$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ and the function $\zeta$ de Riemann in the point 2, this say that using the transform fourier of $x^2$ prove that $\zeta (2)$ is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$, but here is not my trouble because I did this part but the answer me which is the relation between $\zeta(2)$ the fourier tranform of $x^2$?

Comment: You could start by actually evaluating the fourier $series$ of $x^2$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Do you mean the Fourier series (rather than transform)?

Comment: See the answer given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/8378/81360)

Comment: I see, thanks. !

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://quantum.phys.unm.edu/466-15/E02087.pdf)  is the fourier transform of $x^2$.
If you put $x=0$ you get the solution to Basel problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

After you get the Fourier series for $x^2$  in $[−\pi,\pi]$, put $x=\pi$, and there you go!